# ng-class doesn't do what a simple css class does

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I was expecting ng-class to at least do what a simple class does i.e. apply a css property. In the plunker example, if the replace `ng-class` with `class`, it works and I get the indent. 
i.e. `ng-class="indentLeft"` doesn't work but `class="indentLeft"` does. What am I missing ?

See a simple plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/moLu0BmgEYVm3xFQDcw8?p=preview

Comment: If `class` is what you need, then why do you need `ng-class`

Comment: I actually need to do further complicated stuff with ng-class, but if I'm stumbling at the first step, it is not very pleasant. I've reduced my problem to this simple question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ngClass requires an expression to evaluate.

```
ng-class="{'indentLeft' : (item == true)}"
```

The json structure is property name in '' is the class you want to apply and that property value detracted if it should be applied via true/false

*String Expression*

When you do this, `ng-class="indentLeft"` angularjs doesn't know that it is a string and most likely is trying to evaluate it from the scope.

If you wrap the property in '' and make it a string literal the plunker should work correctly

`ng-class="\'indentLeft\'"`

**[Updated plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/wnGJP0ltSvxwAxp1xdAT?p=preview)**

Comment: Pls. elaborate why you think it needs an expression. The documentation says that one of the 3 ways it operates is "If the expression evaluates to a string, the string should be one or more space-delimited class names." I mean, isn't ng-class="indentLeft" an adequate expression in itself ?

Comment: It is not since indentLeft most likely being treated as a unknown scope property.  If you do `'indentLeft'` now it is a string and angular works correctly